# removing duplicate lines that occur every certain number of lines using sed or other

Tags: linux, sed

I have a huge file and I would like to remove duplicate lines that occur only every 3 lines.
Is it possible using sed or any similar command?

My file looks like this:

```
this is text

1234

1234

this is another text

5678

5678
```

the second number is a duplicate of the first and I would like to remove the second number (third line) for each 3 lines of the file. The reason why I'm not using less filename | uniq is that numbers might repeat themselves in the file (outside the 3 lines range) and I don't want them removed then.

Thanks

Comment: What does your data look like exactly?

Comment: yes it is; please update your question with some example input and the required output; makes it so much easier to snswer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your issue?

```
$ awk 'NR%3!=0' input
this is text


1234
this is another text


5678
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed '0~3d' input
this is text


1234
this is another text


5678
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -n -e '$.%3!=0&&print' input
this is text


1234
this is another text


5678
```

But, then again, I might have missinterpreted the question...

Answer (score 1):

The `uniq` utility only filters out adjacent lines (does your input really have a blank line between each line?).  Otherwise it could be used:

```
this is text
1234
1234
this is another text
1234
1234
```

`uniq input.txt` gives:

```
this is text
1234
this is another text
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'n;$!N;s/^([^\n]*)\n\1$/\1/' file
```

Print the first line of three and delete the third line if it is a duplicate of the second.

Answer (score 0):

Making assumptions about what your input really is and what you want to output:

```
awk 'NR%3 == 2 {val=$0} NR%3 == 0 && $0 == val {next} 1' <<END
this is text
1234
1234
this is another text
5678
5678
foo
bar
qux
END
```

```
this is text
1234
this is another text
5678
foo
bar
qux
```